# PDO installation not working?

Tags: php53

I have php version 5.3.22 on Centos Linux.

I currently have this in my phpinfo() output:

```
./configure' '--disable-fileinfo' '--disable-pdo'
```

If I run:

```
pecl install PDO
```

I get:

```
WARNING: "pecl/PDO" is deprecated in favor of "channel://http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/pdo//ext/PDO"
downloading PDO-1.0.3.tgz ...
Starting to download PDO-1.0.3.tgz (52,613 bytes)
.............done: 52,613 bytes
12 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20090626
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
building in /root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rooteYio5E/PDO-1.0.3
running: /root/tmp/pear/PDO/configure
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables...
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /usr/local
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/local/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... re2c
checking for re2c version... 0.13.5 (ok)
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether to enable PDO support... yes, shared
checking for ld used by cc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for BSD-compatible nm... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking dlfcn.h usability... yes
checking dlfcn.h presence... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1966080
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from cc object... ok
checking for objdir... .libs
checking for ar... ar
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for strip... strip
checking if cc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for cc option to produce PIC... -fPIC
checking if cc PIC flag -fPIC works... yes
checking if cc static flag -static works... yes
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking whether the cc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no

creating libtool
appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.h
running: make
/bin/sh /root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rooteYio5E/PDO-1.0.3/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/root/tmp/pear/PDO -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rooteYio5E/PDO-1.0.3/include -I/root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rooteYio5E/PDO-1.0.3/main -I/root/tmp/pear/PDO -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /root/tmp/pear/PDO/pdo.c -o pdo.lo
mkdir .libs
cc -I. -I/root/tmp/pear/PDO -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rooteYio5E/PDO-1.0.3/include -I/root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rooteYio5E/PDO-1.0.3/main -I/root/tmp/pear/PDO -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /root/tmp/pear/PDO/pdo.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/pdo.o
/bin/sh /root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rooteYio5E/PDO-1.0.3/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/root/tmp/pear/PDO -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rooteYio5E/PDO-1.0.3/include -I/root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rooteYio5E/PDO-1.0.3/main -I/root/tmp/pear/PDO -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /root/tmp/pear/PDO/pdo_dbh.c -o pdo_dbh.lo
 cc -I. -I/root/tmp/pear/PDO -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rooteYio5E/PDO-1.0.3/include -I/root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rooteYio5E/PDO-1.0.3/main -I/root/tmp/pear/PDO -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /root/tmp/pear/PDO/pdo_dbh.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/pdo_dbh.o
/root/tmp/pear/PDO/pdo_dbh.c: In function âpdo_stmt_instantiateâ:
/root/tmp/pear/PDO/pdo_dbh.c:410: error: âzvalâ has no member named ârefcountâ
/root/tmp/pear/PDO/pdo_dbh.c:411: error: âzvalâ has no member named âis_refâ
/root/tmp/pear/PDO/pdo_dbh.c: In function âpdo_stmt_constructâ:
/root/tmp/pear/PDO/pdo_dbh.c:435: error: âzend_fcall_infoâ has no member named âobject_ppâ
/root/tmp/pear/PDO/pdo_dbh.c:458: error: âzend_fcall_info_cacheâ has no member named âobject_ppâ
/root/tmp/pear/PDO/pdo_dbh.c: In function âzim_PDO_setAttributeâ:
/root/tmp/pear/PDO/pdo_dbh.c:752: error: âzvalâ has no member named ârefcountâ
/root/tmp/pear/PDO/pdo_dbh.c: In function âzim_PDO_getAttributeâ:
/root/tmp/pear/PDO/pdo_dbh.c:818: error: âzvalâ has no member named ârefcountâ
/root/tmp/pear/PDO/pdo_dbh.c: In function âpdo_hash_methodsâ:
/root/tmp/pear/PDO/pdo_dbh.c:1122: warning: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type
/root/tmp/pear/PDO/pdo_dbh.c:1126: warning: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type
make: *** [pdo_dbh.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pecl PDO` is depricated, try `yum install php-pdo`

Comment: IT says: "No package php-pdo available."